# crypto currencies mining

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, mining-profitability

For now i can't afford a great GPU for mining.
But what i am thinking is...
To mine a very low difficulty coin as much as i can with my old cpu and gpu and wait untill the currency price grow up.
But i am searching and I can't get what i want...
What i am searching about and please i need your help for it.
I want a list of currencies with the lowest difficulty and CAN BE MINED.
I found many with low difficulty but not minable.
So please i need a list of minable currencies with lthe lowest difficulty.
Thanks..